# Crop Corine LC via REST API

Tags: arcgis-rest-api

Using Corine's raster layer and REST API at https://copernicus.discomap.eea.europa.eu/arcgis/rest/services/Corine/CLC2018_WM/MapServer/1, is it possible to pass an extent/bounding box to crop the raster image at this endpoint?

For example, it's possible to return geoJSON which intersects an envelope/polygon on the vector layer with:

```
https://image.discomap.eea.europa.eu/arcgis/rest/services/Corine/CLC2018_WM/MapServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=*&geometry=-5.104%2C51.101%2C4.322%2C53.453&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=4326&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&outSR=4326&f=geojson
```

I would like to perform an analagous query on layer 1 in this dataset, returning a cropped area of extent. Is it possible with this API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, it turns out there is an export endpoint at https://image.discomap.eea.europa.eu/arcgis/rest/services/Corine/CLC2018_WM/MapServer/export

A crop/clip query can be constructed with something like:

```
https://image.discomap.eea.europa.eu/arcgis/rest/services/Corine/CLC2018_WM/MapServer/export?bbox=-5.104%2C51.101%2C4.322%2C53.453&bboxSR=4326&layers=&layerDefs=&size=800%2C800&imageSR=&historicMoment=&format=png&transparent=true&dpi=300&time=&layerTimeOptions=&dynamicLayers=&gdbVersion=&mapScale=&rotation=&datumTransformations=&layerParameterValues=&mapRangeValues=&layerRangeValues=&clipping=&spatialFilter=&f=html
```

Export query parameters for Corine can be found here: https://copernicus.discomap.eea.europa.eu/arcgis/sdk/rest/index.html#/Export_Map/02ss00000062000000/